# how can i resolve "destroy in not a function" when i include my Home component in my app.js to navigate to my Home page i get that error in react js

Tags: reactjs

```
function App() {
  return (
    <div `className`="App">
      <>
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={<Layout />}>
            <Route index element={<Home />} /> //if remove this code the app works fine but once I include        it I start getting the error
          </Route>
        </Routes>
      </>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

am just confused on what to do`

Comment: Do you have `destroy` function in your `Home` comeponent?

Comment: can you share with us more about the  ```Home``` comeponent ?

Comment: @Konrad no I don't

Comment: @Shad0w sure i will be posting the Home components